# Can we execute VTS test framework on Emulator?

Tags: java, android, adb, cts

Can we execute VTS test framework in emulator through android app (Application layer) similar to we do in Personal Device.

Example:

```
vts-tradefed_win.bat
run vts
```

Can these be done through mobile phone by app?

Answer (score 0):

Use VTS to validate HAL level changes with the vendor partition.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-vts/#0

I don't think there is much value in running VTS on an emulator.

Comment: Link-only answers are insufficient, please provide some points from the source.